# Составить запрос через QueryBuilder ManyToOne

Tags: php, mysql, запрос, symfony

Всем салам, в общем есть связь между механиками и сервисами ManyToOne:
Сущность Mechanic

```
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=CarService::class, inversedBy="mechanics")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $carService;
```

В контроллере нужно создать запрос через QueryBuilder. Нужно вывести всех механиков из массива сервисов($carServices - это сущности сервисов):

```
        $i = 0;
        $qb
            ->leftJoin('m.carService', 'cs');
        foreach ($carServices as $carService) {
            $qb
                ->andWhere('cs.id =:id'.$i)
                ->setParameter('id'.$i, $carService->getId());
            ++$i;
        }
```

Я попытался сделать как то так, но выводит пустой массив, работает только для одного сервиса, а если больше то пустой массив. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно запрос составить

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле работает и такой вариант

```
->where('p.parent IS NULL and p.class = :class')
```

То есть в одном where можно задать много критериев поиска.
В этом случае я сначала собираю в массив все критерии типа этого:

```
        //поисковые параметры сообщения
    $message = $request->query->get("message");
    if ($message != null) {
        $constrains [] = self::MESSAGE_TABLE_ALIAS . ".message like '%" . $message . "%'";
    }
    $createdAt = $request->query->get("createdAt");
    if ($createdAt != null) {
        $constrains [] = self::MESSAGE_TABLE_ALIAS . ".created_at = " . $createdAt;
    }

    //поисковые параметры отправителя сообщения
    //username, email, firstname, lastname
    $username = $request->query->get("username");
    if ($username != null) {
        $constrains[] = self::USER_TABLE_ALIAS . ".username = '" . $username . "'";
    }

    $email = $request->query->get("email");
    if ($email != null) {
        $constrains[] = self::USER_TABLE_ALIAS . ".email = '" . $email . "'";
    }

    $firstname = $request->query->get("firstname");
    if ($firstname != null) {
        $constrains[] = self::USER_TABLE_ALIAS . ".firstname = '" . $firstname . "'";
    }

    $lastname = $request->query->get("lastname");
    if ($lastname != null) {
        $constrains[] = self::USER_TABLE_ALIAS . ".lastname = '" . $lastname . "'";
    }
```

а потом делаю implode (" and ", $constrains) и подставляю полученный результат в один where. У меня все работает.
И не стоит размещать этот код в контроллерах. Используйте репозитории (см. Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository).
(Я привел пример из своего проекта как есть. И конструкции типа self::MESSAGE_TABLE_ALIAS или self::USER_TABLE_ALIAS использую для удобства, чтобы префиксы одной таблицы били везде идентичный.)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел у себя ошибку вместо andWhere нужно было orWhere